# как разрешить редактирования сразу?

Tags: jetbrains, rider

При открытии любого файла нельзя просто так и написать туда чтонибудь, обязательно нужно нажимать кнопки shift+insert. Как сделать так чтобы при открытии файла можно было сразу чтонибудь писать?

Comment: Похоже, у вас подключен плагин **IdeaVim**.

Comment: @Spatz, спасибо, вы избавили меня от мучений!

Comment: Добрый день! Вы, случайно, не помните, каким образом этот плагин оказался у вас установленным?

Comment: @Feedforward, когда устанавливал Rider, на 3-4 шаге по умолчанию стояло enable.